# How do I take last n elements from nested collection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I am buinding a chat for an application, so when a user logs in I need to send them all 'unseen' messages, I am using entityframework, Id like to return only the last 20 unseen messages. but my query is not working, currently I get this exception

> Count must be a DbConstantExpression or a DbParameterReferenceExpression

what am I  doing wrong?

```
List<ChatVM> unSeenChats = db.Chats.Where(chat => !chat.Seen)
            .Select(chat => new ChatVM
            {
                Id = chat.Id,
                IsAnnonymous = chat.IsAnnonymous,
                UserName = chat.UserName,
                Messages = chat.Messages
                    .OrderBy(x => x.DateTime)
                    .Skip(chat.Messages.Count - 20 > 0 
                        ? chat.Messages.Count - 20 
                        : 0)
                    .Take(20)
                    .Select(message => new MessageVM
                    {
                        Id = message.Id,
                        DateTime = message.DateTime,
                        Text = message.Text
                    }).ToList()
            }).ToList();
```

my models are as follows:

```
public class Chat
{
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Message> Messages { get; set; }
}
public class Message
{
    ...
    public int ChatId { get; set; }
    public virtual Chat Chat { get; set; }
}
public class Entities : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    ....
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        ...
        modelBuilder.Entity<Message>()
            .HasRequired(p => p.Chat).WithMany(p => p.Messages).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
    }
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you're allowed to use `.Count` from within the query (hence the error that you're seeing). In any case, I think you're looking at this from the wrong perspective. You should probably be using the `OrderByDescending` method, and then just grab the first 20 posts from there.

Something like this:

```
List<ChatVM> unSeenChats = db.Chats.Where(chat => !chat.Seen)
            .Select(chat => new ChatVM
            {
                Id = chat.Id,
                IsAnnonymous = chat.IsAnnonymous,
                UserName = chat.UserName,
                Messages = chat.Messages
                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.DateTime)
                    .Take(20)
                    .Select(message => new MessageVM
                    {
                        Id = message.Id,
                        DateTime = message.DateTime,
                        Text = message.Text
                    }).ToList()
            }).ToList();
```